# Laravel own package serviceprovider not found

Tags: php, laravel, package

I'm making a package in Laravel which requires another package. But I'm getting the following error

> Fatal error: Class 'Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaLibraryServiceProvider' not found

This is my folder structure

[image]

I included my fresh package to my composer, this looks as following

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Notflip\\Cld\\": "packages/Notflip/cld/src/"
}
```

This is what my service provider looks like

```
<?php namespace Notflip\Cld;


use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CldServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->register(\Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaLibraryServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

PHPStorm is complaining that there is multiple definitions of the ServiceProvider and the newly required package Spatie/ can't be found

Here's a screenshot for clarity
[image]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Yes I did! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Composer update --lock` will resolve the problem